# most efficient way to get through array?

Tags: c, arrays, iteration

I have been thinking and was wondering what the fastest algorithm is to get through every element of a (large - lets say more than say 10,000 sized) unsorted int array. My first thought was to go through the linear motion and check every element at a time - then my mind wandered to recursion and wondered if cutting the array into parallels each time and check the elements would be fine.

The goal I'm trying to figure out is if a number (in this kind of array) will be a multiple of a seemingly "randomly" generated int. Then after this I will progress to try and find if a subset of the large array will equate to a multiple of this number as well. (But I will get to that part another day!)

What are all of your thoughts? Questions? Comments? Concerns?

Comment: So you want to "visit" every element in the array and perform some math? Looks like a job for `omp` to me - parallel processing: `#pragma omp parallel for`

Comment: @Floris Yes, I would like to visit every element, but I want to code it myself (sorry, don't know what you're talking about with `omp` and parallel processing). I want an assessment at which of the two options above seems most efficient. Also, the only math done on the array elements is for a check. `if (array[i] % N == 0) ...`

Comment: Since the array is not sorted, recursion will just generate overhead. Go through it linearly - with a conventional `for` loop. As for `omp` - see http://openmp.org/mp-documents/omp-hands-on-SC08.pdf when you have some time. It makes it VERY straightforward to get a big speedup (depending on the # of cores - most machines these days have 4 or more, which can make a significant difference for large calculations). Note that when you use large blocks of memory, accessing them linearly has special speed advantages (cache coherence).

Answer (score 4):

You seem under the false impression that the bottleneck for running through an array sequentially ist the CPU: it isn't, it is your memory bus. Modern platforms are very good in predicting sequential access and doing everything to streamline the access, you can't do much more than that. Parallelizing will usually not help, since you only have one memory bus, which is the bottleneck, in the contrary you are risking false sharing so it could even get worse.

If for some reason you are really doing a lot of computation on each element of your array, the picture changes. Then, you can start to try some parallel stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For an unsorted array, linear search is as good as you can do. Cutting the array each time and then searching the elements would not help you much, instead it may slow down your program as calling functions needs stack maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to process every element of a contiguous array in a single thread is sequentially.  So the simplest solution is the best.  Enabling compiler optimisation is likely to have a significant effect on simple iterative code.

However if you have multiple cores, and very large arrays, greater efficiency may be achieved by separating the tasks into separate threads.  As suggested a using a library specifically aimed at performing parallel processing is likely to perform better and more deterministically that simply using the OS support for threading.

Another possibility is to offload the task to a GPU, but that is hardware specific and requires GPU library support such as CUDA.

All that said 10000 elements does not seem that many - how fast do you need it to go, and how long does it currently take?  You need to be measuring this if performance is of specific interest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform some kind of task on every element of the array, then it's not going to be possible to do any better than visiting each element once; if you did manage to somehow perform the action on N/2 elements of an N-sized array, then the only possibility is that you didn't visit half of the elements. The best case scenario is visiting every element of the array no more than once.

You can approach the problem recursively, but it's not going to be any better than a simple linear method. If you use tail recursion (the recursive call is at the end of the function), then the compiler is probably going to turn it into a loop anyway. If it doesn't turn it into a loop, then you have to deal with the additional cost of pushing onto the call stack, and you have the possibility of stack overflows for very large arrays.

The cool modern way to do it is with parallel programming. However, don't be fooled by everyone suggesting libraries; even though the run time looks faster than a linear method, each element is still being visited once. Parallelism (see OpenMP, MPI, or GPU programming) cheats by dividing the work into different execution units, like different cores in your processor or different machines on a network. However, it's very possible that the overhead of adding the parallelism will incur a larger cost than the time you'll save by dividing the work, if the problem set isn't large enough.

I do recommend looking into OpenMP; with it, one line of code can automatically divide up a task to different execution units, without you needing to handle any kind of inter-thread communication or anything nasty.

Answer (score 0):

The following program shows a simple way to implement the idea of parallelization for the case you describe - the timing benchmark shows that it doesn't provide any benefit (since the inner loop "doesn't do enough work" to justify the overhead of parallelization).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 1000000

int main(void) {
int ii,jj, kk;
int *array;
double t1, t2;
int threads;

// create an array of random numbers:
array = malloc(N * sizeof *array);
for(ii=0; ii<N; ii++) {
  array[ii]=rand();
}

for(threads = 1; threads < 5; threads++) {
  jj=0;
  omp_set_num_threads(threads);
  t1=omp_get_wtime();

// perform loop 100 times for better timing accuracy
  for(kk=0; kk<100; kk++) {
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:jj)
    for(ii=0; ii<N; ii++) {
      jj+=(array[ii]%6==0)?1:0;
    }
  }

  t2=omp_get_wtime();
  printf("jj is now %d\n", jj);
  printf("with %d threads, elapsed time = %.3f ms\n", threads, 1000*(t2-t1));
  }

return 0;

}
```

Compile this with

```
gcc -Wall -fopenmp parallel.c -o parallel
```

and the output is

```
jj is now 16613400
with 1 threads, elapsed time = 467.238 ms
jj is now 16613400
with 2 threads, elapsed time = 248.232 ms
jj is now 16613400
with 3 threads, elapsed time = 314.938 ms
jj is now 16613400
with 4 threads, elapsed time = 251.708 ms
```

This shows that the *answer* is the same, regardless of the number of threads used; but the amount of time taken does change a little bit. Since I am doing this on a 6 year old dual core machine, you don't actually expect a speed-up with more than two threads, and indeed you don't see one; but there is a difference between 1 thread and 2.

My point was really to show how easy it is to implement a parallel loop for the task you envisage - but also to show that it's not really worth it (for me, on my hardware).

Whether it helps for your case depends on the amount of work going on inside your innermost loop, and the number of cores available. If you are limited by memory access speed, this doesn't help; but since the modulo operation is relatively slow, it's possible that you gain a small amount of speed from doing this - and more cores, and more complex calculations, will increase the performance gain.

Final point - the `omp` syntax is relatively straightforward to understand. The only thing that is strange is the `reduction(+:jj)` statement. This means "create individual copies of `jj`. When you are done, add them all together."

This is how we make sure the total count of numbers divisible by 6 is kept track of across the different threads.